# Adding variable with .height()

Tags: jquery

I want to add .eventsHovered to .events when the window gets to a certain height. This works:

```
jQuery(window).bind('scroll', function() {
                 if ($(window).scrollTop() > 201) {
                     $('.events').addClass('eventsHovered');
                         if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300 {
                             $('.events').removeClass('eventsHovered');
                           }
                   }
                 else {
                     $('.events').removeClass('eventsHovered');
                 }
                });
```

However I don't want to set it to 300 as per the above, as the height may grow. I've tried this:

```
jQuery(window).bind('scroll', function() {
             var $height = .height();
             if ($(window).scrollTop() > 201) {
                 $('.events').addClass('eventsHovered');
                     if ($(window).scrollTop() > $height {
                         $('.events').removeClass('eventsHovered');
                       }
               }
             else {
                 $('.events').removeClass('eventsHovered');
             }
            });
```

But it's not working. Please could anyone help?

Comment: is `.height();` correct?

Comment: You have an error here `if ($(window).scrollTop() > $height {` (parenthesis)

Comment: Please try to use the browser's error console. It helps a lot when you see error messages for syntax errors.

Comment: can you please tell us  the.height() of what you want to get? and in the 'working' example you shown, this `if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300 {` will generate an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.height()` operates on a selector, and you have not picked one. You can either use `$(this)`, which refers to the `window` object since you're calling it within the scroll event handler of it, or `$(window)` itself.

Also, `.bind()` is deprecated and you should use `.on()` instead. Your if-else logic can be also improved—based on the code you posted, you basically want to toggle the `eventsHovered` class when the window scrolls beyond 200, but less than its height:

```
jQuery(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var $w = $(window),
        fromTop = $w.scrollTop(),
        wHeight = $w.height();  // or $(this).height()

    if (fromTop > 201 & fromTop < wHeight) {
        $('.events').addClass('eventsHovered');
    } else {
        $('.events').removeClass('eventsHovered');
    }
});
```

---

**Even better:** You might want to also check viewport position relative to the document body when the page is loaded. Sometimes the page is not loaded at the top, and the `eventsHovered` class will not be toggled since the if/else conditionals are only evaluated when a scroll event is fired.

To prevent this, you can define a function, which you will fire both at runtime, and during a scroll event:

```
var eventsToggle = function() {
    var $w = $(window),
        fromTop = $w.scrollTop(),
        wHeight = $w.height();

    if (fromTop > 201 & fromTop < wHeight) {
        $('.events').addClass('eventsHovered');
    } else {
        $('.events').removeClass('eventsHovered');
    }
}

// Execute at runtime
eventsToggle();

// Listen to scroll event
jQuery(window).on('scroll', eventsToggle);
```